# evaluate a python string expression using dictionary values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am parsing a text file which contain python "string" inside it. For e.g.:

```
'my_home1' in houses.split(',') and '2018' in iphone.split(',') and 14 < mask
```

for the example above, I wrote a possible dictionary:

```
dict = {'house' : 'my_home1,my_home2', 'iphone' : '2015,2018', 'mask' : '15' }
```

but `dict` is not know in advance and will be adapted during the running time of the python script.

I would like to replace all the appearance of keys inside the string above in a dynamic way and then to evaluate the expression.

Comment: what is in the variable `houses`

Comment: I hope now it is clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I found a solution to my problem:

```
text = "'my_home1' in houses.split(',') and '2018' in iphone.split(',') and 14 < mask"
dict = {'house' : 'my_home1,my_home2', 'iphone' : '2015,2018', 'mask' : '15' }

expression = 'false'

for key in dict.keys():
    if isinstance(dict.get(key), str):
        text = re.sub(key, '\'{}\''.format(dict.get(key)), text)
    else:
        text = re.sub(key, dict.get(key), text)

eval(text)
```

Answer (score -1):

Is the following what you were expecting:

```
dict_ = {'house': 'my_home1,my_home2', 'iphone': '2015,2018'}
print('my_home1' in dict_['house'].split(',') and '2018' in dict_[
      'iphone'].split(',') and '2019' not in dict_['iphone'].split(','))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately this is not what i am searching. I updated my question.

Comment: my difficulty with your solution is that I do not know in advance the keys inside dict.

Comment: i am not able to get you, can you come again

Comment: I have adapted my example above. The difficulty is that you you do not know  which texts\strings in the expressions are in the dictionary and need to be evaluate with 'dict_'.

Comment: how did you get the possible dictionary? what was the logic behind that