# return raw expresion by dict key?

Tags: python

```
dct={'t1':2>1,'t2':'a'=='b'}
```

dct values is True or False. When using dct['t1'], it will return True. But I want to return raw expression, which means `'2>1'`(the type is string).

- Python version: 3.7

Comment: You can’t unless you store the string. The only thing that ends up in the dict is the result of the expression. That’s how expressions work in python.

Comment: Take a look this, may help u https://stackoverflow.com/a/55385985/7456750

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). For example, maybe you want to store strings (and maybe evaluate them later), or store functions (like lambdas), or it would actually be better to store the results.

Comment: Dicts and other containers will always contain *references to objects*. "expressions" are not objects, they are a feature of source code. You could use a *function object* if you want some behavior

Comment: But this doesn't make much sense to begin with. Your expressions all depend on constants, indeed, the Python interpreter itself probably folds these constants, what are you **actually** trying to accomplish (i.e., this sounds like the X-Y problem)

Answer (score 1):

An expression written in Python and executes will be evaluated, it no longer exists as the expression. I.e. `x = 1 + 2` assigns the value `3` to `x`, there's no memory of that being the result of evaluating `1 + 2`.

But just like in your source code, you *can* save an expression as a string. After all, that's what your source code is, just a long text string.

So:

```py
dct = {'t1': "2>1", 't2': "'a'=='b'"}
print(dct['t1'])
print(eval(dct['t1']))
```

However, keep in mind that `eval()` should only be used in cases where you really need to keep track of this type of stuff. Generally, using `eval()` is not efficient and can be very dangerous, depending on where those strings come from.

Comment: so I have to convert value to string.

Comment: I you look at the example in my answer, there's not really 'conversion' to string going on, the original expressions in the dictionary definition are *defined* as strings with the double quotes around them (using double quotes to avoid problems with the single quotes in your second expression)

Comment: Why not use a function? A string and `eval` is just convoluted for this case

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - the whole point of the question seemed to be that OP wants to have access to both the original expression and the resulting value. That's where `eval()` shines, although I agree with @wjandrea that this is most likely just a matter of an XY problem and OP probably doesn't really need access to the expressions to begin with.

Comment: @Grismar you are probably right. Re-reading this, I'm not sure I really understand what the OP is asking